# The instrument that show the attitude in the F-16 cockpit in a dive glide slope but nose up attitude what will show?

Tags: military, flight-instruments, f-16

An [F-16 Fighting Falcon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Dynamics_F-16_Fighting_Falcon) is nose up at 25 degrees [angle of attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_attack) (AoA) and unable to keep the level flight path  but it is in a $600$ feet per minute dive slope. Does the [attitude direction indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attitude_indicator) (ADI) show more of the sky or more of the ground?

Comment: Angle of attack is not a variable in the pitch attitude of the airplane.  You can be at any AoA at any pitch attitude.   What is the power setting?

Comment: The power setting is on the left side of the curve ,but I'm interested only the attitude showed on ADi ,regardless of the /climb /dive (here)velocity.

Comment: 600 FPM is 3 degrees or so flightpath below the horizon at normal approach speeds; it would be perhaps 1 degree below the horizon at 250 knots. So if your flightpath is -1 to -3 and your AoA is +25, your pitch can be estimated, as long as one assumes thing like wings level and some sort of reasonable airspeed. (If assumptions can include unreasonably slow forward speeds, ie a VTOL hanging in the air with barely any forward or vertical speed, then everything is "possible", if pretty wildly hypothetical.)

Comment: "An F-16...  is nose up at 25 degrees angle of attack (AoA)" -- this sentence is confusing.  The implication is that "25 degrees" is meant to specify exactly how "nose up" the plane is.  It sounds like you meant to say the *pitch attitude* is 25 degrees.  Did you?  Or did you mean to say something like "The nose is above the horizon at some unspecified angle, and the angle of attack is 25 degrees" --?  Pitch attitude and angle of attack are two completely different things.  Or by "is nose up" did you *not* actually mean that a/c was in a positive (nose-up) pitch attitude? Please clarify.

Comment: (As long the a/c really "is nose up" relative to the horizon, the answer seems obvious.)  On the other hand if the question is only meant to specify that the a/c is nose-up *relative to the flight path*, then you really need to say that explicitly, because that's not what we normally mean by "nose up".   As it stands now the question is confusing.

Comment: Please do not make pointless edits to closed questions, as these serve no good purpose but "bump" the question to the top of recent activity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the nose of the airplane is above the horizon the ADI will show more sky than ground.

Rate of descent, AoA, and power setting are all irrelevant.  The ADI displays only attitude with respect to the earth's horizon.

Comment: Adding to this excellent answer, (totally correct without any irrelevant additional details), in the HUD, which also displays aircraft attitude as the HSI does, among the other info displayed is a *flight path* marker, which is positioned over the spot representing the aircrafts current wind- corrected flight path or velocity vector. The difference or displacement between the two represents the aircrafts AOA, sideslip angle, and any wind correction.

Comment: true , but I want to isolate the ADi .

Comment: @GeorgeGeo what exactly are you trying to isolate? Michael Hall’s answer is correct. The pitch attitude of the aircraft (what is shown on the ADI) is what matters, not the AOA or velocity vector.

Comment: @Timbo, I think George was referring to Charles' comment.  (i.e. he isn't interested in  extra information about the HUD, sideslip, velocity vector, etc...)

Comment: The only reason (albeit a minor one) to add these extraneous details, would be to educate the op about what these other variables (like AOA, sideslip angle, etc. etc. ), are, how they relate to aircraft pitch attitude, which *is* displayed on the ADI, so that the answer to his question might make more sense to him. As his question, as worded, might betray a fundamental confusion about the relationship of these concepts.

Comment: Charles, I always welcome feedback, but this is the second time recently that you have suggested a lot of what you admit are extraneous details to an answer of mine.  You are super smart and experienced, but please answer yourself if you truly think the information is useful.  I'm not saying it isn't, just that while I might sometimes expound significantly, other times I choose to simply answer what was asked.

Comment: @Michael, I am sorry you are so easily affected by my contributions to this forum. Indeed, when I contribute to a thread here where you are involved, to eliminate potential misunderstanding, I have made a conscious effort to include comments that acknowledge and praise your contribution to the issue at hand. However, I do not participate or contribute here to stroke my ego, or anyone else's, or to accumulate reputation points. I participate to contribute, when I can, to a more thorough and complete understanding of aviation and aeronautical concepts within the general aviation community.

Comment: @Michael, I deliberately added these extra details as a comment, rather than as a separate answer, because, indeed, your answer was totally correct, and directly answered the op's question. It does not *need* any additional details. What I added in a comment would on no way be a complete answer to his question. It would be incomplete and confusing as a separate answer.  However, in future, when I comment on one of your posts, I will word my comments to make it more explicit that I am not implying any fault or criticism of your answer.

Comment: @CharlesBretana, there's no need to apologize.  I am not easily affected. (much less offended...)  Don't treat me with kid gloves.  We are both here for the very same reasons, and have also tried to thank and praise you.  It's just an observation.  Simple questions sometimes deserve simple answers, that's all.  I try to match my level of effort with the OPs effort and apparent knowledge.

Comment: I'm not complaining... AT ALL.  But if I were to complain it would only be that we end up in a long conversation like this...  But I get it too, there are others besides the OP who might learn something.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you say that. No worries with me then.  I am probably overly concerned about how my pedantic nature can at times be misread by others.